# How to embed Python code with matplotlib in interactive mode into C?

Tags: python, c, matplotlib

I'd like to re-use a Python script that makes use of matplotlib in interactive mode by embedding a call to it from a C application -- what do I need to do in order to get interactive mode in an embedded Python script working?

I set up an extremely simple example using PyRun_SimpleString(); it works when interactive mode is turned off, but when interactive mode is on the plot window only shows up for a brief interval right before the application ends

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime,sleep\n"
                       "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n"
                       "import matplotlib\n"
                       "print(matplotlib.get_backend())\n"
                       "plt.ion()\n"
                       "plt.plot([1,2,3,4,3,5,7])\n"
                       "sleep(5)\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

The backend used by matplotlib is Qt4Agg.  When I execute the lines above in the Python interpreter, it behaves as I'd expect.  If I change the plt.ion() to a plt.ioff() and put in a plt.show() after the plt.plot() call, I also see the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say, "[w]hen I execute the lines above in the Python interpreter, it behaves as I'd expect," you're referring to running it within the Python command line/REPL. The right way to test one to one behavior with embedded Python would be to instead place your in a python script and then try running it with `python script.py`.

You'll notice that within a script your code gives a similar problem. I think the trick is to use `plt.pause(5)` instead of `sleep(5)`, this allows the event loop for the plot GUI to fire and actually draw the window properly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35119003/11365663).

For REPLs, matplotlib has some [extra magic](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/5e9c54e7c4feb296b387fadb56394ef67ac2927f/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L579-L590) so that the details of the event loop are hidden from you.

This worked for me:

```c
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime,sleep\n"
                       "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n"
                       "import matplotlib\n"
                       "print(matplotlib.get_backend())\n"
                       "plt.ion()\n"
                       "plt.plot([1,2,3,4,3,5,7])\n"
                       "plt.pause(5)\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation -- the comments you made regarding the even loop made perfect sense and introducing the pause() call did the trick -- thanks for pointing out what was going on under the hood with matplotlib, too.   I appreciate your help ...